# draw mandlebrot onto bitmap

Tags: java, c#, bitmap

I am currently converting java code into c# code and i have it almost working i think but I am trying to draw the mandlebrot onto the bitmap but nothing is displaying . The form pops up but nothing is drawn onto it.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace Assignment1
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                init();
                start();
                stop();
                destroy();
                InitializeComponent();

            }


            public struct HSBColor
            {
                float h;
                float s;
                float b;
                int a;

                public HSBColor(float h, float s, float b)
                {
                    this.a = 0xff;
                    this.h = Math.Min(Math.Max(h, 0), 255);
                    this.s = Math.Min(Math.Max(s, 0), 255);
                    this.b = Math.Min(Math.Max(b, 0), 255);
                }

                public HSBColor(int a, float h, float s, float b)
                {
                    this.a = a;
                    this.h = Math.Min(Math.Max(h, 0), 255);
                    this.s = Math.Min(Math.Max(s, 0), 255);
                    this.b = Math.Min(Math.Max(b, 0), 255);
                }

                public float H
                {
                    get { return h; }
                }

                public float S
                {
                    get { return s; }
                }

                public float B
                {
                    get { return b; }
                }

                public int A
                {
                    get { return a; }
                }

                public Color Color
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return FromHSB(this);
                    }
                }

                public static Color FromHSB(HSBColor hsbColor)
                {
                    float r = hsbColor.b;
                    float g = hsbColor.b;
                    float b = hsbColor.b;
                    if (hsbColor.s != 0)
                    {
                        float max = hsbColor.b;
                        float dif = hsbColor.b * hsbColor.s / 255f;
                        float min = hsbColor.b - dif;

                        float h = hsbColor.h * 360f / 255f;

                        if (h < 60f)
                        {
                            r = max;
                            g = h * dif / 60f + min;
                            b = min;
                        }
                        else if (h < 120f)
                        {
                            r = -(h - 120f) * dif / 60f + min;
                            g = max;
                            b = min;
                        }
                        else if (h < 180f)
                        {
                            r = min;
                            g = max;
                            b = (h - 120f) * dif / 60f + min;
                        }
                        else if (h < 240f)
                        {
                            r = min;
                            g = -(h - 240f) * dif / 60f + min;
                            b = max;
                        }
                        else if (h < 300f)
                        {
                            r = (h - 240f) * dif / 60f + min;
                            g = min;
                            b = max;
                        }
                        else if (h <= 360f)
                        {
                            r = max;
                            g = min;
                            b = -(h - 360f) * dif / 60 + min;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            r = 0;
                            g = 0;
                            b = 0;
                        }
                    }

                    return Color.FromArgb
                        (
                            hsbColor.a,
                            (int)Math.Round(Math.Min(Math.Max(r, 0), 255)),
                            (int)Math.Round(Math.Min(Math.Max(g, 0), 255)),
                            (int)Math.Round(Math.Min(Math.Max(b, 0), 255))
                            );
                }

            }




        private const int MAX = 256;      // max iterations
        private const double SX = -2.025; // start value real
        private const double SY = -1.125; // start value imaginary
        private const double EX = 0.6;    // end value real
        private const double EY = 1.125;  // end value imaginary
        private static int x1, y1, xs, ys, xe, ye;
        private static double xstart, ystart, xende, yende, xzoom, yzoom;
        private static bool action, rectangle, finished;
        private static float xy;
        private Image picture;
        private Graphics g1;
        private Cursor c1, c2;
        //private HSB HSBcol=new HSB();



        public void init() // all instances will be prepared
        {
            //HSBcol = new HSB();
            this.Size = new Size(640,480);
            finished = false;
            //addMouseListener(this);
            //addMouseMotionListener(this);
            //c1 = new Cursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR);
            //c2 = new Cursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR_CURSOR);
            x1 = this.Width;
            y1 = this.Height;
            xy = (float)x1 / (float)y1;
            Bitmap img = new Bitmap(1, 1);
            g1 = Graphics.FromImage(img);
            finished = true;

        }

        public void destroy() // delete all instances 
        {
            if (finished)
            {
                //removeMouseListener(this);
                //removeMouseMotionListener(this);
                picture = null;
                g1 = null;
                c1 = null;
                c2 = null;
                GC.Collect(); // garbage collection
            }
        }

        public void start()
        {
            action = false;
            rectangle = false;
            initvalues();
            xzoom = (xende - xstart) / (double)x1;
            yzoom = (yende - ystart) / (double)y1;
            mandelbrot();
        }

        public void stop()
        {
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            update(g); 
        }

        public void update(Graphics g)
        {
            g.DrawImage(picture, 0, 0);
            if (rectangle)
            {
                Pen WhitePen = new Pen(Color.White);
                if (xs < xe)
                {
                    if (ys < ye) g.DrawRectangle(WhitePen, xs, ys, (xe - xs), (ye - ys));
                    else g.DrawRectangle(WhitePen, xs, ye, (xe - xs), (ys - ye));
                }
                else
                {
                    if (ys < ye) g.DrawRectangle(WhitePen, xe, ys, (xs - xe), (ye - ys));
                    else g.DrawRectangle(WhitePen, xe, ye, (xs - xe), (ys - ye));
                }
            }
        }

        private void mandelbrot() // calculate all points
        {
            int x, y;
            float h, b, alt = 0.0f;
            Pen FractalPen;


            action = false;
            //SetCursor(c1);
            //showStatus("Mandelbrot-Set will be produced - please wait...");
            for (x = 0; x < x1; x+=2)
                for (y = 0; y < y1; y++)
                {
                    h = pointcolour(xstart + xzoom * (double)x, ystart + yzoom * (double)y); // color value
                    if (h != alt)
                    {
                        b = 1.0f - h * h; // brightnes
                        ///djm added
                        //HSBcol.fromHSB(h,0.8f,b); //convert hsb to rgb then make a Java Color
                        Color color = HSBColor.FromHSB(new HSBColor(h * 255, 0.8f * 255, b * 255));  // VERY IMPORTANT
                        //g1.setColor(col);

                        //djm end
                        //djm added to convert to RGB from HSB

                        //g1.setColor(Color.getHSBColor(h, 0.8f, b));
                        //djm test
                    //Color col = Color.getHSBColor(h,0.8f,b);
                    //int red = col.getRed();
                    //int green = col.getGreen();
                    //int blue = col.getBlue();
                        //djm 
                    alt = h;
                    FractalPen = new Pen(color);
                    g1.DrawLine(FractalPen, x, y, x + 1, y); 
                    }           

                }
            //showStatus("Mandelbrot-Set ready - please select zoom area with pressed mouse.");
            //setCursor(c2);
            action = true;
        }

        private float pointcolour(double xwert, double ywert) // color value from 0.0 to 1.0 by iterations
        {
            double r = 0.0, i = 0.0, m = 0.0;
            int j = 0;

            while ((j < MAX) && (m < 4.0))
            {
                j++;
                m = r * r - i * i;
                i = 2.0 * r * i + ywert;
                r = m + xwert;
            }
            return (float)j / (float)MAX;
        }

        private void initvalues() // reset start values
        {
            xstart = SX;
            ystart = SY;
            xende = EX;
            yende = EY;
            if ((float)((xende - xstart) / (yende - ystart)) != xy ) 
                xstart = xende - (yende - ystart) * (double)xy;
        }

        /*public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) 
        {
            e.consume();
            if (action)
            {
                xs = e.getX();
                ys = e.getY();
            }
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
        {
            int z, w;

            e.consume();
            if (action)
            {
                xe = e.getX();
                ye = e.getY();
                if (xs > xe)
                {
                    z = xs;
                    xs = xe;
                    xe = z;
                }
                if (ys > ye)
                {
                    z = ys;
                    ys = ye;
                    ye = z;
                }
                w = (xe - xs);
                z = (ye - ys);
                if ((w < 2) && (z < 2)) initvalues();
                else
                {
                    if (((float)w > (float)z * xy)) ye = (int)((float)ys + (float)w / xy);
                    else xe = (int)((float)xs + (float)z * xy);
                    xende = xstart + xzoom * (double)xe;
                    yende = ystart + yzoom * (double)ye;
                    xstart += xzoom * (double)xs;
                    ystart += yzoom * (double)ys;
                }
                xzoom = (xende - xstart) / (double)x1;
                yzoom = (yende - ystart) / (double)y1;
                mandelbrot();
                rectangle = false;
                repaint();
            }
        }

        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
        {
        }

        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
        {
        }

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
        {
        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
        {
            e.consume();
            if (action)
            {
                xe = e.getX();
                ye = e.getY();
                rectangle = true;
                repaint();
            }
        }

        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
        {
        }

        public String getAppletInfo()
        {
            return "fractal.class - Mandelbrot Set a Java Applet by Eckhard Roessel 2000-2001";
        }*/

        }
    }
```

Comment: When are you actually calling `paint`/`update`? And there should be a `PictureBox` on the form that displays the image. Where are you using that? Also, this code is designed like a lazy breakfast. You could really turn that to something nicer with some refactoring.

Comment: did you succeed in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Bitmap img = new Bitmap(1, 1);
```

This could be the problem. You forgot to replace it with width,height. Like this

```
 Bitmap img = new Bitmap(x1, y1);
```

Comment: And as Yorye Nathan said, you forget to do something like, picturebox1.Image = img

Answer (score 0):

call your paint method like this (picturebox is not needed, but for me it was fastest when painting with winforms:

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
var g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
var pea = new PaintEventArgs(g, r);

yourPaintMethod(pea);
```

calls:

```
public void yourPaintMethod(PaintEventArgs e ) {
  Graphics g = e.Graphics;
  Pen pBlack = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
  g.DrawLine(pBlack........ etc.
```